# Material UI Datetimepicker Style

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, datetimepicker

I have this DateTimePicker component from Material ui:

[DateTimePicker Material UI - Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uexak.png)

But it doesn't look like the original one from https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker

Is there any property that I'm missing?

Comment: Coul you please include your code.

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is live to view anywhere? It looks like you have something that is altering the style somewhere but without looking at it all would be hard to say where